# Performing a less-than check on an installed driver

Tags: powershell

I need to develop a Powershell script to detect when a particular installed driver is less than the desired version. So far I'm using this to generate a list of drivers and versions:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | Sort-Object devicename
```

This will return a list like:

```
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller                                               7.37.1229.2010
System board                                                                     6.1.7601.17514
WAN Miniport (PPTP)                                                              6.1.7601.17514
```

How can I select the row containing "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller", parse the version number and take action if the version is less than X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My basic tests show me that you need to cast those as `[version]` then you should be able to do comparisons like `-gt`, `-lt` ...etc. Consider the following statements:

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> "10.37.1229.2010" -lt "8.136.51229.2010"
True

PS C:\Users\Matt> [version]"10.37.1229.2010" -lt [version]"8.136.51229.2010"
False
```

Using a calculated property we cast the driver version as `[version]` then do a sort. Now it should be sorted properly by version.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| 
    select devicename, @{Name="DriverVersion";Expression={[version]$_.DriverVersion}} | 
    Sort DriverVersion
```

Drilling down past that should be easy and accurate now with a where object clause that checks for the devicename and driverversion matching certain criteria

```
Where-Object{$_.DeviceName -eq"Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" -and $_.Driverversion -lt "8.0.0.0"}
```

Comment: Alternatively keep the `DriverVersion` property as is and use an anonymous calculated property with `Sort-Object`: `|sort {$_.DriverVersion -as [version]}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I figured it was easier this way since the title talked about doing other comparisons. Saves recasting all the time. Either way though

Comment: Thanks for the lead on doing the comparison. The missing step is how to select the driver version property for the row that returns device name "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller". Your example assumes that I have already captured that into a variable.

Comment: @user3342256 Added to the answer. I thought the version was just holding you back from that part.